# Jenkins HttpRequest plugin MissingMethodException

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

In my jenkins pipeline, I historically have invoked curl from the command line to make http requests, and I'm looking to streamline it.

I installed the HttpRequest plugin on my jenkins deployment, and I'm running a basic pipeline to test it out.  However, when I run a snippet that I generated from the snippet generator, I get this exception.

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.httpRequest() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[authentication:myJenkinsAuth, url:https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/commits/123456789/status]]

The line of code I'm using is:

```
def response = httpRequest authentication: 'myJenkinsAuth', contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', url: "https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/commits/${commitSHA}/status"
```

The version of the HTTP Request Plugin I'm using is 1.8.22

I'm unsure why the method definition wouldn't be found, to my knowledge, this is exactly what the documentation is telling me I should do, which aligns with the snippet jenkins generated for me.  Any insight would be appreciated.  I can offer more info if I missed any useful details

**Edit**:
I believe the job this is being run in is a freestyle job, and the actual code is being run inside a groovy postbuild step (in the post-build actions section)

Comment: Where do you execute `def response = httpRequest ...` - in job's pipeline script or in Jenkins' script console? The error you have shown suggests that you are running it from Jenkins' script console, where `httpRequest` method does not exist (this plugin has to be used inside pipeline script).

Comment: That's a good point, it's being run inside a job in a groovy postbuild block.  The "Use Groovy Sandbox" option is unchecked (not sure if that affects anything)

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @hpereira Sorry to say, I never found a solution.  Even now I'm still just invoking curl in my pipelines to make http requests.

Comment: try `def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(new URL("https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/commits/${commitSHA}/status").getText())`

Answer (score 2):

Took me awhile to realize my similar issue was a scoping problem. Not sure if you are calling httpRequest within a static method, but if so remove static.

MyScript.groovy:

```
static def myMethod() {
    httpRequest acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
                url: url,
                <...>
}
```

Gradle error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static 
>   **MyScript**.httpRequest() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) 
>   values: [[<...>

It's looking for httpRequest within MyScript. Oops... Removing static worked.